# Jquery filter giving empty results

Tags: jquery, filter

Why is this not working. I'm getting an empty array.

```
<select id="test">
<option value="Bar">Foo</option>
<option value="Bar1">Foo1</option>
<option value="">Foo2</option>
<option value="Bar3">Foo3</option>
<option value="Bar4" selected>Foo4</option>
<option value="Bar5">Foo5</option>
</select>

$('#test').find('option').filter(function() {
 this.selected && this.value.length
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` your condition.